# having an issue when edited a row again it is inserting a new row in php codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter

i have an issue with edit and update a row which is having file upload field.
my problem is when i inserting a row if there is a file uploaded then inserting the row, then when edited it is not showing file and again asking file to upload.
here is my controller:

```
public function addclient()
{
            $logo = 'logo';
            $status = "";
            $msg = "";
            $file_extension = "";
            $this->load->library('form_validation');

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('name','Name','trim|required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('location', 'Location', 'trim|required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('address', 'Address', 'trim|required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('mobile', 'Mobile', 'trim|required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('landline', 'Land Line', 'trim|required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('personname', 'Contact Person Name','trim|required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('persondesignation', 'Contact Person Designation', 'trim|required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('personmobile','Contact Person Mobile','trim|required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email Address','trim|required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('personemail','Contact Person Email Address','trim|required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('otherinfo','Other Information','trim|required');
            //$this->form_validation->set_rules('logo','Logo','trim');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('url','Website Url','trim|required');



            if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
            {
                $status = 'error';
                echo $msg = validation_errors();
                //echo json_encode(array('st'=>0, 'msg' => validation_errors()));
            }
            /******* extracting file extension ********/
            $org_filename = $_FILES['logo']['name'];
            //$path_parts = pathinfo($org_filename);
            //$file_extension = $path_parts['extension'];
            $file_extension = pathinfo($org_filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            /***** end extracting file extension ******/

            $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/client';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
            $config['max_size'] = 1024 * 1000;       
            $final_file_name = $config['file_name'] = 'client_'.time().'.'.$file_extension;

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            if (!$this->upload->do_upload($logo))
            {
               $error = $this->upload->display_errors();
               echo $error;
               //echo json_encode($error);
            }
            else
            {
                //...save values to database 
                $this->load->model('vadmin/clientmodel','',true);
                $this->clientmodel->addUpadteClientForm($final_file_name);
                $status = 'success';
                echo  'Submitted ok...!';
            }      

}
```

here is my model function:

```
public function get($client_id)
{  
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".TB_CLIENTS." WHERE client_id='".$client_id."'";
    $ex = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $ex->row_array();  
}
public function addUpadteClientForm($final_file_name = '')
  {

    $name = $this->input->post('name');
    $location = $this->input->post('location');
    $address = $this->input->post('address');
    $mobile = $this->input->post('mobile');
    $landline = $this->input->post('landline');     
    $personname = $this->input->post('personname');
    $persondesignation = $this->input->post('persondesignation');
    $personmobile = $this->input->post('personmobile');
    $email = $this->input->post('email');
    $personemail = $this->input->post('personemail');
    $otherinfo = $this->input->post('otherinfo');
    $partnerflag = $this->default_client_partner_flag;
    $logodisplayflag = $this->default_client_logo_display_flag;
    $logo = $final_file_name;
    $url = $this->input->post('url');
    $status = $this->default_client_status ;

    $client_id = $this->input->post('id');

     if(is_numeric($client_id) && $client_id > 0)
    {
        //mysql_real_escape_string or addslashes()
        //edit query

        $sql = "UPDATE ".TB_CLIENTS." SET 
    client_name='".mysql_real_escape_string($name)."',client_location='".mysql_real_escape_string($location)."',client_address='".mysql_real_escape_string($address)."',client_mobile='".mysql_real_escape_string($mobile)."',client_landline_number='".mysql_real_escape_string($landline)."',client_contact_person_name='".mysql_real_escape_string($personname)."',client_contact_person_designation='".mysql_real_escape_string($persondesignation)."',client_contact_person_mobile='".mysql_real_escape_string($personmobile)."',client_email_address='".mysql_real_escape_string($email)."',client_contact_person_email_address='".mysql_real_escape_string($personemail)."',client_other_info='".mysql_real_escape_string($otherinfo)."',partner_flag='".mysql_real_escape_string($partnerflag)."',logo_display_flag='".($logodisplayflag)."',logo='".mysql_real_escape_string($logo)."',client_website_url='".mysql_real_escape_string($url)."',status='".mysql_real_escape_string($status)."'  WHERE client_id='".mysql_real_escape_string($client_id)."'" ;
    echo $sql;
    }
    else
    {
      $sql = "INSERT INTO ".TB_CLIENTS." (client_name,client_location,client_address,client_mobile,client_landline_number,client_contact_person_name,client_contact_person_designation,client_contact_person_mobile,client_email_address,client_contact_person_email_address,client_other_info,partner_flag,logo_display_flag,logo,client_website_url,status)
            VALUES (".$this->db->escape(trim($name)).",".$this->db->escape(trim($location)).",".$this->db->escape(trim($address)).",".$this->db->escape(trim($mobile)).",".$this->db->escape(trim($landline)).",".$this->db->escape(trim($personname)).",".$this->db->escape(trim($persondesignation)).",".$this->db->escape(trim($personmobile)).",".$this->db->escape(trim($email)).",".$this->db->escape(trim($personemail)).",".$this->db->escape(trim($otherinfo)).",".$this->db->escape(trim($partnerflag)).",".$this->db->escape(trim($logodisplayflag)).",".$this->db->escape(trim($logo)).",".$this->db->escape(trim($url)).",".$this->db->escape(trim($status)).")";

     return $this->db->query($sql); 
  }
}
```

Comment: you must use Active Record implementation of CodeIgniter to make it secure.

Comment: thats ok but now i want to edit and update it.

Answer (score 0):

You are only running query when `if(is_numeric($client_id) && $client_id > 0)` is `false` only else part is running the query

change

```
   return $this->db->query($sql); 
 }
```

to

```
 } //  move this up
 return $this->db->query($sql);
```

Comment: thaks for reply, and that is not my problem when editing again asking file has to upload. if i upload when edit then submit it is inserting another record.